# The requested file (go1.13.7.linux-amd64.tar.gz) is unknown to the buildpack when pushing golang web app to heroku?

Tags: go, heroku

I have created a golang REST API and am trying to deploy it to heroku. I've built it on windows 7.

I linked my github account to push my golang web app to heroku, but I am getting the following error:

`The requested file (go1.13.7.linux-amd64.tar.gz) is unknown to the buildpack!`

I am using [dep](https://github.com/golang/dep) to package my app. Here is the metadata i provide to heroku in my Gopkg.toml:

```
[metadata.heroku]
  root-package = "restapitest"
  go-version = "go1.13.7"
  install = [ "./..." ]
```

My file project folder looks like this:

```
C:\$GOPATH\src\API\RESTAPI\

                           Vendor\github.com\gorilla
                                             go-sql-driver
                           Gopkg.lock
                           Gopkg.toml
                           main.go
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appeared to be an issue with the version. Lowering it to 1.12.0 allowed successful deployment of the app.

Comment: this is still an issue as of 2022. Very annoying, tbh. Instead of using 1.19 it's forcing to use 1.12.... nothing above it worked for me.